# Is there an Count Function for Row Counts which works with ELSE Function?

Tags: salesforce, ampscript, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a code where Voucher Details should be displayed. Id there is no voucher, nothings should be displayed. 
We use a RowCount > 0 but the RowCount seems not to give back 0 if there is nothing in the Data Extension.

How to change the If Statement or the ELSE statement.

```
%%[
SET   @voucherXML = AttributeValue("Vouchers")    
// build a rowset from the XML
SET @voucherRows        = BUILDROWSETFROMXML(@voucherXML, "//voucher", 1)
SET @voucherNames       = BUILDROWSETFROMXML(@voucherXML, "//voucher//name", 1)
SET @voucherAmounts      = BUILDROWSETFROMXML(@voucherXML, "//voucher//amount", 1)      
]%%


%%[If RowCount(@voucherRows) > 0 Then
FOR @index = 1 TO RowCount(@voucherRows) DO
// retrieve the items form the rowset from 1 to the count of rows   
]%%



      <p class="bdetails__bill__title" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.07em; line-height: 1.8em; Margin: 0; font-size: 11px;">
        %%=FIELD(ROW(@voucherNames,@index),
          "Value")=%%
        </p>


      <p class="bdetails__bill__value" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.07em; line-height: 1.8em; Margin: 0; text-align: right;">
        -%%=FIELD(ROW(@voucherAmounts,@index),
          "Value")=%%
       </p>


  <!--
%%[
NEXT @index
]%% -->
 <!--%%[ELSE]%%-->

<h2 class="bdetails__title" style="color: #0b0b0b; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 600; line-height: 1.385em; Margin: 0; font-size: 24px; text-transform: uppercase; width: 100%; min-width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        Bestelldetails
      </h2>
 <!--%%[ENDIF]%%
--> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by assigning the value to a variable first and then referencing that temporary variable. Try changing your code to do the following:

```
SET @rowcount = RowCount(@voucherRows)
IF @rowcount >= 1 THEN
```

This should resolve the issue. If not, you can simply use the [`ISNULL`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/isnull.htm) function instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can be written as

```
IF NOT EMPTY (@voucherRows) THEN

// No of statements 

ELSE 
// statements

ENDIF
```

Thanks